# Why instantiate variables with a null value

Tags: java, programming-languages

In many pieces of example code I see variables instatiated with null values and later assigned more meaningful values.

I was just wondering why people may do this. I'm guessing try-catch blocks may well come into this, but I also see variables instantiated will null values inside of a try block.

(I'm sure this is a fairly language agnostic question, but just for reference I program almost entirely in Java)

All insights appreciated!

Comment: I think that's a valid question. +1 to balance the downvote.

Comment: That's what happens when the downvoter doesn't leave a comment.

Comment: Simply because in a lot of cases otherwise the code simply won't compile.  Now why the Java specs mandates this is another question but +1 to MForster who pointed out the exact compiler error message.  Note that you don't even need to compile a valid *.java* file to get this error message.  For example: IntelliJ IDEA (amazing Java IDE) will warn you about your **error** in real-time, even on a partial AST (that is: a partial .java file that you couldn't compile yourself because it is incomplete).

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd LOL, +1 to balance the downvote... I hate those people  with higher reputation on SO downvote those poor guys every where.

Answer (score 14):

The Java compiler detects in certain cases if a variable has not been initialized in all possible control flows and prints an error. To avoid these error messages, it's necessary to explicitly initialize the variable.

For example in this case:

```
  public Integer foo() {
    Integer result;

    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
      result = 1;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

The compiler would give this error message: "The local variable result may not have been initialized".

Here is what the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/defAssign.doc.html#25979) says:

> Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final (§4.5.4)
>   field (§8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when
>   any access of its value occurs. A Java compiler must carry
>   out a specific conservative flow analysis to make sure that,
>   for every access of a local variable or blank final field f,
>   f is definitely assigned before the access; otherwise a
>   compile-time error must occur.

Note that (in contrast to fields!) local variables are not automatically initialized to `null`.

Comment: It issues an error to help you avoid runtime exceptions!  I wouldn't say it's necessary.  In fact, I'd say it's very poor to not make sure each control flow had a valid object.

Comment: I was referring to the error message by the compiler. I think these are even mandated by the language specification.

Comment: Does anyone else think it's strange that QuakerOat asked this question, and wheaties commented on an answer?

Comment: @MikeG my comment didn't refer to his editted answer, but to the original.  Saying "assign it to null so not to throw that error" instead of how it now reads "explicitly initialize the variable" is akin to saying "just put some empty try/catch blocks around it" instead of "handle the exceptions with try/catch blocks."

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I edited the answer to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I don't like it for member fields that will take a value in the constructor.  There was a time when I thought it was just nice to be explicit, but there's actually a bytecode difference between assigning a field to null explicitly or the field taking the default value.

Even for fields that do start out as null (and then gain a value sometime after initialization) I'm not a big fan of them.  It usually just highlights misunderstanding from the developer that did that.

The try-catch relevance is in cases like this:

```
Reader r = null;
try {
    r = ...;
    //do something that could throw an exception
} finally {
    if ( r != null ) { //wouldn't compile without assignment to null
        r.close();
    }
}
```

Because `r` is a local variable here it needs a value before it can be used, so the assignment is necessary.  If the assignment to null happens in the same code path as its subsequent reassignment and/or use, that's probably just misleading redundancy.

Comment: I typically only produce code using immutable objects so member fields that take a value in the constructor are typically all marked as *final* in my code, which makes the point kinda moot: in that case you simply cannot assign it *null* first then change it in the CTOR.

Comment: @Webinator:  Definitely.  A nice side effect of final members.

Answer (score 0):

YES, thought about this question many times.

For now, I usually give a initial value `null` for a object, and a meanless value for simple type. The reason, sometimes you dont cant sure that the JRE gives initial value to the variable. And sometimes you need to judge weither the variable is null, maybe you forget init it. Some bugs is easy to find, If gives variables a initial value.